# Use VCL Styles From Delphi XE7 to Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe7, vcl-styles

I have copied all files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Redist\styles\vcl to C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\Redist\styles\vcl

In my XE2 IDE, I go to Projects->Options->Application->Appearance and the others styles from XE7 doesn't appear.

I also have copied C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Styles to C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Styles but it make all styles disappear.

How to make XE2 IDE read the new styles from another version of IDE?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not going to work. VCL styles have changed loads.

Comment: Oh that's bad for me. The reason why I don't want to use XE7 because some components has no available yet e.g mustangpeakvirtualshelltools

Comment: If you have the source it will be trivial to make those components work with xe7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The internal format of the *vsf files* (styles) was changed in the XE3 version (v 2.0). So the styles included in XE7 version can't be used in XE2.

- XE2 - can use only the VCL Styles version 1.0
- XE3-XE7 - can use any VCL style (version 1.0 or 2.0)